# Library for country location select

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

Is there any JavaScript or JSF library on which I can select contry and display available company addresses? For example I found this Flash solution:

http://www.solaredge.com/groups/to_order

The fest solution for me will be to use Google maps into my web site and when visitors want to find office based on country location to use this Map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution based on Google Maps.

The logic is:

1. Create a offices list by country.
2. Listen the `click` event on the map.
3. Get the country name by using the [`Geocoder`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) service.
4. Display the offices details from the array.

**The full code** (based on [Google demo](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/country_explorer/country_explorer.html)) - Click on Germany for example.

```js
var offices = {
  'germany': [
    {
      name: 'germany1',
      address: 'germany1 address'
    }
  ]
};

var geocoder;
var marker;
var chartBase = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=';

function getCountry(results) {
  var geocoderAddressComponent,addressComponentTypes,address;
  for (var i in results) {
    geocoderAddressComponent = results[i].address_components;
    for (var j in geocoderAddressComponent) {
      address = geocoderAddressComponent[j];
      addressComponentTypes = geocoderAddressComponent[j].types;
      for (var k in addressComponentTypes) {
        if (addressComponentTypes[k] == 'country') {
          return address;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return 'Unknown';
}
function getCountryIcon(country){
  return chartBase + 'd_simple_text_icon_left&chld=' +
    escape(country.long_name)  + '|14|999|flag_' +
    country.short_name.toLowerCase() + '|24|000|FFF';
}
function getMsgIcon(msg){
  return  chartBase + 'd_bubble_text_small&chld=edge_bl|' + msg +
    '|C6EF8C|000000';
}
function initialize() {
  // created using http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html
  var styleOff = [{ visibility: 'off' }];
  var stylez = [
    {   featureType: 'administrative',
     elementType: 'labels',
     stylers: styleOff},
    {   featureType: 'administrative.province',
     stylers: styleOff},
    {   featureType: 'administrative.locality',
     stylers: styleOff},
    {   featureType: 'administrative.neighborhood',
     stylers: styleOff},
    {   featureType: 'administrative.land_parcel',
     stylers: styleOff},
    {   featureType: 'poi',
     stylers: styleOff},
    {   featureType: 'landscape',
     stylers: styleOff},
    {   featureType: 'road',
     stylers: styleOff}
  ];
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.012924,18.59848),
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeId: 'Border View',
    draggableCursor: 'pointer',
    draggingCursor: 'wait',
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: ['Border View']
    }
  });
  var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(stylez,
                                                    {name: 'Border View'});
  map.mapTypes.set('Border View', customMapType);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(53.012924,18.59848),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(mouseEvent) {
    var redMarkerIcon = chartBase +
        'd_map_xpin_letter&chld=pin|+|C40000|000000|FF0000';
    marker.setIcon(redMarkerIcon);
    //map.setCenter(mouseEvent.latLng);
    geocoder.geocode(
      {'latLng': mouseEvent.latLng},
      function(results, status) {
        var headingP = document.getElementById('country');
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          var country = getCountry(results);
          marker.setPosition(mouseEvent.latLng);
          marker.setIcon(getCountryIcon(country));
          //headingP.innerHTML = country.long_name+ ' <br> ';
          headingP.innerHTML = '';
          var country_offices = offices[country.long_name.toLowerCase()];
          if (country_offices) {
            for (var i = 0; i < country_offices.length; i++) {
              headingP.innerHTML += '<div>Office name: ' + country_offices[i].name + '. Office address: ' + country_offices[i].address + '</div>'
            }
          }
        }
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
          marker.setPosition(mouseEvent.latLng);
          marker.setIcon(
            getMsgIcon('Oups, I have no idea, are you on water?'));
          headingP.innerHTML = 'Oups, ' +
            'I have no idea, are you on water?';
        }
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
          marker.setPosition(mouseEvent.latLng);
          marker.setIcon(
            getMsgIcon('Whoa! Hold your horses :) You are quick! ' +
                       'too quick!')
          );
          headingP.innerHTML = 'Whoa! You are just too quick!';
        }
      });
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
#country {
  text-align: center;
}
#map_canvas {
  height: 75%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title> 
      Google Maps V3 API Sample #2:  Clik to find out  what country you are in
    </title> 
    <link
          href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css"
          rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
    <style type="text/css"> 

    </style> 
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

    </script> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <p align="center" id="country"> Click on a map to find out what country you
      clicked on. <br> This code sample shows how to create styled maps and how
      to generate and handle geocoding requests. It also shows how to use the
      chart api to generate dynamic icons. </p> 
    <div id="map_canvas"></div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/tijevu/edit?html,css,js

[image]

Comment: Thanks. One question where are the offices displayed?

Comment: In http://jsbin.com/tijevu/edit?html,css,js I got error Line 99: Missing semicolon.

Comment: The offices shown before the map http://i.stack.imgur.com/8m06B.png. This error is nothing - I was fixed this..

Comment: I noticed that when I click on a country, the country is placed at the center. Can you disable this please?(just comment the code)

Comment: I was commented the code.. `map.setCenter(mouseEvent.latLng);`

Comment: Hm... I removed it from the code but now the flag is not moved over the country that I click.